# How Can I Count Hide Tab Pages?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, visibility

I Have A Tab Control And Several Tab Pages In It
This Tab Control Is A Component,Tab Pages Have "Page Visible" Property For Declaring Visibility And Tab Control Have Pages.Count Property
Some Of These Tab Pages Are Hidden
How Can I Count Hide Tab Pages(Or Visible Ones)??

Comment: TabControl is a control, not a component.  TabPages do not have a Visible property (that is visible from the designer).  If you want help, you will have to document your question much better than this.

Comment: What I Meant Was: Its A Control That Added By Installing A Component! And This Component(Or Control Whatever) Does Have A Tabpage.PageVisible Property

Comment: That doesn't change how poorly documented your question is.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful to remember the TabControl is a Container. It contains a collection of TabPages. You "hide" a TabPage be removing it from the TabControl's collection. You can evaluate the collection to see which/how many of the tabs are present.

Comment: In Design Mode Exactly, But Tab Pages Can Be Added Or Removed(Hide , Show) By The User In Run Mode, So...

Answer (score -1):

Following from your comment earlier you could use something like this:

```
var visiblePages = tabControl.Pages.Cast<YourTabPage>().Where(page => page.PageVisible).Count()
```

Comment: I Told You What Property's I Have For Answering The Question And I Can't Put A Reference To My Question Unless I Upload The Project Or The Component(Copyright Wont Le Me) But Thanks For Your Respond And I Found A Way By Set An Index For Every Tabpage And Using "Selected Page Index" Property

Comment: Well if you have a PageVisible property then you can use tabControl.Pages.Cast<YourTabPage>().Where(page => page.PageVisible).Count() to get the visible ones.

Comment: Thanks @James I Think That,ll Work With A Little Change ;)
 I Just Didn't Know How To Use "Where<>"